# Is it okay to use the verb, "collapse," to mean, "cause something to collapse"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, grammaticality, idiomatic-language, grammaticality-in-context

In some dictionaries, it says we can say "collapse" to mean, "cause something to collapse" (You can see some examples on [Oxford's American dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/collapse).) But the other dictionaries don't mention that. Do you think it is okay to use, "collapse," to mean that? For example, do you think the examples below are correct?

> 1. The engineers collapsed the old building using explosives.
> 2. A bear collapsed our shack last night.
> 3. Hearing the news of his father's death collapsed him.
> 4. The earthquake collapsed many buildings yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

You can collapse a wave function (in physics), or someone's argument (in a debate), a building, a tent, a house of cards, in fact you can pretty much use the verb transitively to mean 'cause something to collapse'. There is no restriction in meaning to do with folding and packing away. The meaning is possible in US and British English.

> transitive verb
>
> 1: to cause to collapse
> buildings collapsed by an earthquake
>
> He knelt for a long time, first watching the bay below, then collapsing the
> spyglass and settling his hands on his legs in a thoughtful pose. —

[Collapse (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collapse)

1.1 with object
Cause (something) to fall down or give way.

it feels as if the slightest pressure would collapse it

many people tend to collapse the distinction between the two concepts

Or the pressure could collapse the hole altogether.

[Collapse (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/collapse)

Answer (score -1):

You can use *collapse* transitively but none of your examples works unfortunately. If you collapse something you fold it up into a smaller object or space. So you might collapse a tent in order to pack it away or collapse a folding table.

Comment: Thanks. You can actualy see examples similar to mine in Oxford dictionary: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/collapse Maybe it is an American English vs British English thing.

Comment: You can collapse a wave function (in physics), or someone's argument (in a debate), a building, a tent, a house of cards, in fact you can pretty much use the verb transitively to mean 'cause something to collapse'. There is no restriction in meaning to do with folding and packing away.

Comment: I don't have a problem with any of OP's examples. Looks like @MichaelHarvey thinks the same.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey how strange. For me collapse as a transitive verb is definitely a subset of cause to collapse.

Comment: @FireandIce no, it is just my idiolect I think as MichaelHarvey and I are both in the same nation.

Comment: It's in both Merriam-Webster (American focus) and Oxford (British focus) which is why I said it is possible in US and British English in my answer 20 hours ago.